# How can I download file from magnet link on Ubuntu server?

Tags: 14.04, server

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04 (not Ubuntu desktop), and I would like to download some large files to it using a magnet link so I don't need to wait for a whole day to upload them from my local machine using scp.

Is this possible? What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Try looking into transmission-daemon https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks! That's exactly what I need. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a P2P (peer-to-peer) software for Ubuntu, for instance BitTorrent, Amule, or gtk-gnutella. It'll open magnet links.

Here's a [page with instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/P2PHowTo) for using P2P software on Ubuntu.